# @RestController autoserialize POJO's

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a Spring mvc application, with a `@RestController` like such:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("levels")
public class LevelController {

  private final GetLevelOneCount getLevelOneCount;

  private final GetLevelTwoCount getLevelTwoCount;

  private final GetLevelThreeCount getLevelThreeCount;

  @Inject
  public LevelController(GetLevelOneCount getLevelOneCount, 
      GetLevelTwoCount getLevelTwoCount,
      GetLevelThreeCount getLevelThreeCount) {
    this.getLevelOneCount = getLevelOneCount;
    this.getLevelTwoCount = getLevelTwoCount;
    this.getLevelThreeCount = getLevelThreeCount;
  }


  @GetMapping("/level1/{id}")
  public LevelModel levelOne(@PathVariable String id) throws SQLException {
    LevelModel levelOneModel = new LevelModel();

    levelOneModel.setLevelQuery(getLevelOneCount.execute(id));
    levelOneModel.setLevelDirQuery(getLevelOneCount.executeDir(id));
    levelOneModel.setLevelDateQuery(getLevelOneCount.executeDate(id));

    return levelOneModel; 
}
```

my `LevelModel` is a POJO with private variables, now i wonder, if this can get serialized to propper JSON with private variables?

```java
package com.pwc.tag.service.levels;

public class LevelModel {

    private Long LevelQuery;

    private Long LevelDirQuery;

    private Long LevelDateQuery;

    public Long getLevelQuery() {
        return LevelQuery;
    }

    public void setLevelQuery(Long levelQuery) {
        LevelQuery = levelQuery;
    }

    public Long getLevelDirQuery() {
        return LevelDirQuery;
    }

    public void setLevelDirQuery(Long levelDirQuery) {
        LevelDirQuery = levelDirQuery;
    }

    public Long getLevelDateQuery() {
        return LevelDateQuery;
    }

    public void setLevelDateQuery(Long levelDateQuery) {
        LevelDateQuery = levelDateQuery;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your object will be serialized to a proper JSON structure including the private field, because of the [getters and setters](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not).

If these fields should not be present in the output object, you can add the `@JsonIgnore` annotation to exclude them from the JSON structure.

P.S. the common approach is to start names of java properties with a lower case letter.